# correct Regex settings or the expression itself

Tags: c#, regex, list, split

I have a text like this:

> "2008/00419 Bir kompresör ARÇELİK ANONİM ŞİRKETİ 2008/00438 Su altı
> canlı ürün nakil pompası DENİZSAN DENİZCİLİK ANONİM ŞİRKETİ 2008/03300
> YAĞLI AĞARTMA TOPRAKLARINDAN YAĞIN VE AĞARTMA TOPRAĞININ GERİ KAZANIM
> YÖNTEMİ MAYSA YAĞ SANAYİ ANONİM ŞİRKETİ"

I need to split this text into "number + text" records. Like this:

1. 2008/00419 Bir kompresör ARÇELİK ANONİM ŞİRKETİ
2. 2008/00438 Su altı canlı ürün nakil pompası DENİZSAN DENİZCİLİK
   ANONİM ŞİRKETİ
3. 2008/03300 YAĞLI AĞARTMA TOPRAKLARINDAN YAĞIN VE AĞARTMA TOPRAĞININ
   GERİ KAZANIM YÖNTEMİ MAYSA YAĞ SANAYİ ANONİM ŞİRKETİ*

I use a regular expression like this:

```
Regex splitRegex = new Regex(@"(?>(\d{4}\/\d{5}))");

List<string> notes = splitRegex.Split(text).ToList();
```

**But the result I get is like this:**
[image]

Help me choose the correct Regex settings or the expression itself. Thank.

Comment: What's wrong with the results? It's exactly what I'd expect to see from using `Split`.

Comment: I would like to see the number and description in one entry. So that the List contains not 6 records, but 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!
Using a regular expression like this:**

Regex splitRegex = new Regex(@"(?=\d{4}/\d{5})",RegexOptions.Multiline);

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this, but I think you simply want to include the non-numeric portion in your regex pattern?

```
Regex splitRegex = new Regex(@"(?x) # ignore whitespace and comments
    (?<record> # define capturing group
        \d{4} # match 4 digits
        \/ # match forward-slash
        \d{5} # match 5 digits
        [^\d]+ # match following text that is not a digit
    )
");
```

If I remember correctly calling Split() with this will result in an array with empty-strings between each match.. ie. the "delimiter" you're splitting on is the text you wish to capture.  So it's a bit awkward.

I wouldn't think of this as a "splitting" problem.  It would be clearer to call Regex.Matches() and simply enumerate the results, that way.  Pseudocode:

```
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(inputText))
{
    string record = m.Groups["record"].Value;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the split function.

```
// Split text(assigned str), separated by a space followed by "2" 
            string[] recordList = str.Split(" 2");
            Console.WriteLine(recordList[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("2" + recordList[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("2" + recordList[2]);
```

This will return your desired output and will work for any other records as long as the year is 2000's